# Dynamic sorting in QueryDSL

Tags: jpa, querydsl

Lets say I have an Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Date birthdate;
}
```

and I would like to have method which will return `OrderSpecifier` for a field of this entity based on `String` parameter which will be name of one of entities fields.

```
/**
 * fieldName - name of field from Person entity
 */
private OrderSpecifier<?> getSortedColumn(Order order, String fieldName){
    //how to implement this???        
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I actualy managed to do it like this:

```
/**
 * fieldName - name of field from Person entity
 */
private OrderSpecifier<?> getSortedColumn(Order order, String fieldName){
    Path<Object> fieldPath = Expressions.path(Object.class, QPerson.person, fieldName);     
    return new OrderSpecifier(order, fieldPath);
}
```

Comment: how about direction ?

Comment: The order parameter is the one that specifies the direction

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it using the field path that works with any Q type

```
    public static OrderSpecifier<?> getSortColumn(EntityPathBase<?> entity, Order order, String fieldName) {

        final var entityPath = new PathBuilder<>(entity.getType(), entity.getMetadata().getName());
        final var sortColumnPath = entityPath.getComparable(fieldName, Comparable.class); //All sorting columns should be implementing Comparable

        return switch (order) {
            case ASC -> sortColumnPath.asc();
            case DESC -> sortColumnPath.desc();
        };
    }
```

I'm making use of some Java 17+ features, but you can still do without.
then use it with any Q type i.e.

```
getSortColumn(QPerson.person, "name");
getSortColumn(QCat.cat, "dateOfBirth");
```

and you don't have to manually construct new instance of `OrderSpecifier` and deal with 'use of raw type' warnings.